# powershell cant get json key / value

Tags: json, powershell, file, fileparsing

Hello I have a json file below:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "AST.NxTestware.main": "1.1.0",
    "otherPackagenName": "7.7.7"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78": {}
  }
}
```

and I am trying to write a .ps1 powershell script that will look at every item under 'dependencies', check if the name matches, and if so, retrieve the version number.

but I am having trouble parsing through each item in 'dependencies', and cannot retrieve the package name string or version number

My ps1 looks like this:

```
$targetName = "otherPackagenName"
Write-Host "Trying to get version # of $targetName if it exists inside project.json"

# get json file contents
$json = Get-Content .\project.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# retrieve dependencies 
$dependencies = $json.dependencies
Write-Host "dependencies = $dependencies"

# iterate through each dependency
foreach ($dep in $dependencies) {
    Write-Host "dep = $dep"

    # try to get dependency name (attempt1)
    $depName1 = $dep[0]
    Write-Host "depName1 = $depName1"
    
    # try to get dependency name (attempt2)
    $depName2 = $dep.Name
    Write-Host "depName2 = $depName2"

    if($depName1 -eq $targetName) {
        write-host "Found it! now get version number"
    } else {
        write-host "Did not find our package"
    }  
}
```

output shows it correctly retrieves the json key/value pair, but I cant figure out how to retrieve the package name and version number, as every thing ive tried just returns blank:

```
Trying to get version # of otherPackagenName if it exists inside project.json
dependencies = @{AST.NxTestware.main=1.1.0; otherPackagenName=7.7.7}
dep = @{AST.NxTestware.main=1.1.0; otherPackagenName=7.7.7}
depName1 = @{AST.NxTestware.main=1.1.0; otherPackagenName=7.7.7}
depName2 =
Did not find our package
```

my dependencies is coming through like so:

```
@{AST.NxTestware.main=1.1.0; otherPackagenName=7.7.7}
```

**How can I iterate through this object?**

**How can I retrieve the key ('AST.NxTestware.main') and value ('1.1.0') for each dependency?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for this:

```
$json.Dependencies | ForEach-Object {
    $prop = $_.PSObject.Properties

    [pscustomobject]@{
        DependencyName = $prop.Name
        Version        = [version] $prop.Value
    }
}
```

You can get an object's property **Name** and property **Value** by accessing the object's [`PSObject` member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject), from there you can reference the [`Properties` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-psobject-properties) of each object.

Comment: how do i retrieve these values from the `[pscustomobject]@{` ? can i print out 'DependencyName" and 'Version" ? I need to make a function which returns these values

Comment: @POVR2 the code as is will print to the console, you don't really need to use `Write-Host` to print to the console

Comment: the code you provided does not write to console `AST.NxTestware.main` or `1.1.0`